# C# Помогите оптимизировать приложение, в погоне за скоростью не уложился в память, memory limit ecx

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Что где можно позакрывать и как лучше? Никогда этим не занимался, всегда хватало памяти

Задача:

Ограничение времени 1.5 секунд

Ограничение памяти  64Mb

Ввод    input.txt

Вывод   output.txt

Дано целое положительное число k. Также дана последовательность из целых положительных чисел. Необходимо записать в выходной файл "1", если в последовательности есть два числа сумма, которых равна значению k или "0" если таких нет.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Int32> m = new List<Int32>();
            Int32 k = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
            {
                k = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                m = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
                //   m = s.Cast<Int32>();
                sr.Close();
            }
            m.Sort();
            bool flag = false;
            //убираем большие числа
            IEnumerable<Int32> queryOptim;
            if (k % 2 == 0)  // чётное
            {
                queryOptim =
                    from i in m
                    where i < k
                    select i;
                m = queryOptim.ToList();

                List<Int32> rep = new List<Int32>();//отдельно прогоним повторы
                var set = new HashSet<Int32>();
                foreach (Int32 i in m)
                {
                    if (!set.Add(i))
                        rep.Add(i);
                }
                foreach (Int32 i in rep)
                {
                   if (i+i==k)
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
                        {
                                sw.WriteLine(1);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }


                queryOptim =
                    from i in m
                    where i % 2 == 0
                    select i;

                List<Int32> m1 = queryOptim.Distinct().ToList(); //все чётные

                queryOptim =
                    from i in m
                    where i % 2 == 1
                    select i;
                m = queryOptim.Distinct().ToList();  //все нечётные

                int max = m.Count();

                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    if (flag)
                        break;

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < max; j++)
                    {
                        if (m[i] + m[j] > k)
                        {
                            max = j - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        if (m[i] + m[j] == k)
                        {
                            flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                if (!flag)
                {
                    max = m1.Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                    {
                        if (flag)
                            break;

                        for (int j = i + 1; j < max; j++)
                        {
                            if (m1[i] + m1[j] > k)
                            {
                                max = j - 1;
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            if (m1[i] + m1[j] == k)
                            {
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


            }

            else // нечётное
            {
                queryOptim =
                    from i in m
                    where i < k
                    select i;
                m = queryOptim.Distinct().ToList();

                queryOptim =
                    from i in m
                    where i % 2 == 0
                    select i;

                List<Int32> m1 = queryOptim.Distinct().ToList(); //все чётные

                queryOptim =
                    from i in m
                    where i % 2 == 1
                    select i;
                m = queryOptim.ToList();  //все нечётные

                int max = m.Count();
                int max1 = m1.Count();

                for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
                {
                    if (flag)
                        break;

                    for (int j = 0; j < max1; j++)
                    {
                        if (m[i] + m1[j] > k)
                        {
                            max1 = j - 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        if (m[i] + m1[j] == k)
                        {
                            flag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }





            }


            //m = queryOptim.ToList();

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
            {
                if (flag)
                    sw.WriteLine(1);
                else
                    sw.WriteLine(0);
            }
          //  Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Новая программа , проблема та-же

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Int32> m = new List<Int32>();
            Int32 k = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
            {
                k = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                m = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
                //   m = s.Cast<Int32>();
                sr.Close();
            }
            m.Sort();
            bool flag = false;
            //убираем большие числа
            IEnumerable<Int32> queryOptim;

            queryOptim =
                from i in m
                where i < k
                select i;
            m = queryOptim.ToList();

            List<Int32> rep = new List<Int32>();//отдельно прогоним повторы
            var set = new HashSet<Int32>();
            foreach (Int32 i in m)
            {
                if (!set.Add(i))
                    rep.Add(i);
            }
            set = null;
            foreach (Int32 i in rep)
            {
                if (i + i == k)
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(1);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
            rep = null;

            m = m.Distinct().ToList();

            int j = 0;

            if(m.Count==0)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(0);
                }
                return;
            }
            while ((m[j] * 2) < k )
            {
                if (m.Contains(k-m[j]))
                {

                        flag = true;
                        break;

                }
                j++;
                if (j >= m.Count)
                    break;
            }


            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
            {
                if (flag)
                    sw.WriteLine(1);
                else
                    sw.WriteLine(0);
            }
            //  Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

3-я версия

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {




            List<Int32> m = new List<Int32>();
            Int32 k = 0;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("input.txt"))
            {
                k = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                m = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
                //   m = s.Cast<Int32>();
                sr.Close();
            }
            bool flag = false;






            HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
            foreach (var i in m)
            {
                if (set.Contains(k - i))
                {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
                set.Add(i);
            }

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("output.txt"))
            {
                if (flag)
                    sw.WriteLine(1);
                else
                    sw.WriteLine(0);
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а чего оно делает то?  И можно код как то к более читаемому виду привести? Что за переменые `k`, `m`, `rep` и тд?

Comment: Я насчитал 4 коллекции, которые хранят одно и то же. Вам они точно все нужны?

Comment: Программа ищет в коллекции m 2 таких числа, чтобы m[i]+m[j]==k.  
rep это временная коллекция, которая хранит повторы,просто допустим может быть такой случай-(1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,....) и тогда у меня один раз проверится 2+2==k, после этого все повторы убираются. Одно и то-же нигде не хранится, в 
m сначала все числа хранятся, потом туда всё нечётные заносятся, в m1 все чётные, в rep список повторов, в set временные числа для того чтобы понять, очередное число в цикле повтор или нет. Я думал просто сборщик мусора должен сам очистить rep и  set,  но получается это не так?

Comment: Сборщик мусора очистит тогда, когда ему понравится. Это может быть и в начале или в конце выполнения вашего приложения

Comment: по сути, вам надо для каждого `m[i]` найти число `k-m[i]` и проверить наличие этого числа в вашем наборе данных. Это очень легко делается, используя словарь, где ключ = это число из вашего массива `m[i]`, а значения - это идексы, по которым дэто число в исходном массиве хранится.

Comment: Эх, даа, всё гениальное просто, а учитывая что мне даже не индексы надо найти, а сам факт существования таких чисел-это пару строк)

Comment: индексы вам понадобятся, если например, у вас есть число 3 в массиве, а искомое k будет 6. Тогда k-m[i] = 6-3 = 3, то есть вам надо будет убедиться что у вас две тройки в массиве.

Comment: В общем, я соединил ваше решение со своим, сначала нашёл повторы отдельно, по ним прошёлся, после по всем остальным уникальным записям вашим способом (программу добавил ), но проблема осталась, не проходит проверку на память... 
P.S. если использовать словарь вместо моего прохода по парам, я думаю памяти и подавно не хватит?

Comment: Приведите полное условие задачи (с ограничениями)

Comment: Добавил условия

Comment: Количество и диапазон чисел?

Comment: Никаких ограничений на это нет, учитывая опыт предыдущих задач, знаю что числа укладываются в int32, ну и положительные они. Тестирует автомат Яндекса. А, и на тесте, на котором заваливается, пишет что 99 мб использовано памяти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что то вы перемудрили.

Вариант с хешсетом. И не надо никаких сортировок нигде, оно работает как на сортированных, так и на не сортированных массивах.

```
public bool Solve(int k, int[] m)
{
    HashSet<int> set = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach(var i in m){
        if (set.Contains(k-i)) return true;
        set.Add(i);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Как проверить

```
int[] m = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3 }; 

Console.WriteLine(Solve(1, m));
Console.WriteLine(Solve(2, m));
Console.WriteLine(Solve(3, m));
Console.WriteLine(Solve(4, m));
```

Вывод

```
False
False
True
True
```

---

**UPD**

Если мы экономим память, то можно читать число по одному из потока, но имейте ввиду, что работа с файлами без буфера будет медленной операцией.

Нам понадобятся:

Метод, который по коду символа распознает число

```
private bool IsDigit(int c) => c >= '0' && c <= '9';
```

Метод, который умеет считывать число из потока

```
private int readNumber(StreamReader sr)
{
    int c = 0;
    int number = 0;
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        c = sr.Read();
        if (IsDigit(c))
        {
            number = c - '0';
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                c = sr.Read();
                if (IsDigit(c)) number = number * 10 + (c - '0');
                else
                {
                    return number;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```

Основая часть алгоритма

```
var fname = @"D:\temp\_test\qqqq.txt";
using (var sr = new StreamReader(new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fname), 1024*1024))) // небольшой буфер
{
    int k = readNumber(sr);     
    var set = new HashSet<int>();

    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        int number = readNumber(sr);
        if (set.Contains(k-number)) {
            Console.WriteLine("YES");
            return;
        }
        set.Add(number);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("NO");        
}
```

Файл на входе

```
60
1 2 3000001 4 5 6 7000002 8 9 051
```

Вывод

```
YES
```

Comment: Счётчик одинаковых кажется лишним, если сразу проверять.

Comment: @MBo как сразу проверять?

Comment: Перед добавлением i в словарь проверять, есть ли там k-i

Comment: @MBo согласен, сйечас перепишу.

Comment: @MBo готово. Так даже лучше, спасибо!

Comment: О как компактно получилось ;)

Comment: Да, это вообще прям высший пилотаж, но опять те же 99 мб это в памяти весит... Тут по ходу работу с памятью надо курить я так понимаю? МБ на с++ попробовать написать, есть смысл?

Comment: З.Ы. забыл добавить, что там есть описание - Все числа используемы в задаче находятся в диапазоне 0 < N < 999999999 .

Comment: @Петр Иванов  `0 < N < 999999999` Я же об этом в явной форме спрашивал...

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, оно там внизу маленьким шрифтом, не заметил сразу тогда...Но в любом случае же, UInt16 сюда не вставишь...

Comment: Вообще у меня есть подозрения что при считывании строки уже не хватает памяти, как думаете?

Comment: Эх, битовая карта на это количество 128 мегабайт требует

Comment: Много памяти жрёт строка, которую преобразуют в список. Подумайте о том, что в конце моего ответа.

Comment: @ПетрИванов пробуйте апдейт

Comment: @MBo  попробовал считывать посимвольно, хотя навряд ли олимпиадники также делают :)

Comment: @tym32167 Я не знаю, как они на шарпе делают. Просто видел, что на C++ ввод больших данных тоже оптимизируют. И мне приходилось чинить программу обработки логов. Со временем логи стали гигабайтными, чтение всего файла  сразу накрылось.

Comment: Уфф, всем спасибо, всё работает) Изменил немного под свой стиль, вместо isDijit поставил  if (c==' '), ибо других сиволов кроме пробела и цифры быть не может. Теперь на том тесте 63ms / 2.33Mb) Жаль конечно что не сам всё докумекал, ну что поделаешь раз балбес)

Answer (score 0):

1) Прочитали k и список чисел

2) Прошли по списку, игнорируя числа, большие k.
Для очередного числа x проверяем наличие k-x в мапе.
Если есть, выводим 1.
Добавляем x в мап (если он уже есть - пофиг)

3) Дошли до конца - выводим 0

Все остальные действия с сортировкой, отбором и хранением повторов -  лишние.

Если есть другая возможность быстро выделять числа из входной строки (как олимпиадники на C# 'это делают?), то даже иметь и хранить список не нужно.