# Дано число x. Нужно найти сумму чисел равную x, с ограничениями по времени и памяти

Tags: java

Дано целое положительное число "x". Также дана последовательность из целых положительных чисел. Необходимо записать в выходной файл "1", если в последовательности есть два числа сумма, которых равна значению "x" или "0" если таких нет. Ограничение времени 1 секунда, Ограничение памяти 64Mb, Ввод input.txt, Вывод output.txt. 
Мой пример:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s;
    int result;
    int target = 0;
    String nums = "";
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        boolean isFirst = true;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (isFirst) {
                target = Integer.parseInt(s);
                isFirst = false;
            } else {
                nums = s;
            }
        }
        int[] intArr = fromStringToIntArray(nums);
        result = getResult(intArr, target);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(result));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}

private static int[] fromStringToIntArray(String nums) {
    String[] numsArr = nums.split(" ");
    int[] intArr = new int[numsArr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numsArr.length; i++) {
        intArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numsArr[i]);
        numsArr[i] = null;
    }
    return intArr;
}

private static int getResult(int[] intArr, int target) {
    Arrays.sort(intArr);
    int result = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int last = intArr.length - 1;
    while (first < last) {
        int ss = intArr[first] + intArr[last];
        if (ss == target) {
            result = 1;
            break;
        } else {
            if (ss < target) {
                first++;
            } else {
                last--;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1129324/179763

Comment: что не так с вашим примером?

Comment: Не проходит по ограничению памяти

Comment: Тогда смотрите ссылку, что я вам кинул

Comment: tym32167 Большое спасибо за помощь, информация из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1129324/179763 очень помогла

Comment: Запостите свое решение тут ответом? Думаю, это будет полезно сообществу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
static int result = 0;
static int nextInt;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("input.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
         BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        setResult(br);
        bw.write(String.valueOf(result));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}


private static void setResult(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    int a;
    int target;
    int number = 0;
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    target = getNumber(br, getNextNumber(br));
    while ((a = getNextNumber(br)) != -1) {
        if (IsDigit(a)) {
            number = getNumber(br, a);
            if (set.contains(target - number)) {
                result = 1;
                break;
            }
            set.add(number);
        }
    }
}

private static boolean IsDigit(int c) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

private static int getNextNumber(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
    nextInt = br.read();
    return nextInt;
}

private static int getNumber(BufferedReader br, int a) throws IOException {
    int num = a - '0';
    while (IsDigit(getNextNumber(br))) {
        num = num * 10 + (nextInt - '0');
    }
    return num;
}
}
```

Comment: я бы на вашем месте `target` прочитал отдельно от основного алгоритма. Это сделает код гораздо проще, вам не понадобится `isFirst` вообще.

Comment: Спасибо, вы правы, это было бы логичнее и кода станет меньше

Comment: Немного доработал